# find curvature of an image of a mug in PIL?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to paste an image over a mug no there will there stills left, center, right of the mug on each of them I have to show the part of the image pasted. Now the mug on a 2-D  screen has some curvature, So the image pasted will also have to have the same curvature. How do I do this?? One thing I thought is if somehow I can find out the curvature of the bottom part I can maintain the same distance and paste each small part by cropping every time and then pasting it again at same distance from the bottom curvature???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bash script called [cylinderize](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/cylinderize/) that uses ImageMagick to achieve this effect.

So depending on what exactly your goal is, you could either just use this script or try to reverse engineer the algorithm they used.

I think the algorithm you described might not result in a realistic looking picture. You only apply the distortion in the `y` direction and ignore the distortion in the `x` direction.